# How to use NetworkOperatorHotspotAuthenticationTrigger in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, hotspot

I want develop an UWP app use to login to paid wifi. So I have refered to NetworkOperatorHotspotAuthenticationTrigger. When I register background task with that trigger, I was received "Access is denied".

Has anyone done it?

Comment: Hi there, any update? Did my answer solve your problem? Is it an [acceptable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

As it is declared in [NetworkOperatorHotspotAuthenticationTrigger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.networkoperatorhotspotauthenticationtrigger):

> **Note**  An app can only instantiate this object and register for the hotspot authentication event after a WLAN profile has been provisioned that references this app to handle hotspot authentication.

So please make sure you have provisioned a WLAN profile with a corresponding configuration before using this class. If not, you will get `Access is denied.` error while registering.

For more info, please see [Integrating Windows with wireless hotspots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt244301(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Wi-Fi hotspot authentication sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Wi-Fi-hotspot-authenticatio-943569eb).